# Dynamic filtration in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have code for filtration. But the data which filtered was static data. Now I want that data comes from database. Here I shown code snippet for that.

here is the script:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#demo').jplist({             
        itemsBox: '.list' 
        ,itemPath: '.list-item' 
        ,panelPath: '.jplist-panel' 
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is the html design:

```
<div 
           class="jplist-group"
           data-control-type="checkbox-group-filter"
           data-control-action="filter"
           data-control-name="themes">

           <input 
              data-path=".architecture" 
              id="architecture" 
              type="checkbox"                                   
           /> 

           <label for="architecture">Architecture</label>

           <input 
              data-path=".christmas"                                        
              id="christmas" 
              type="checkbox" 
           /> 

           <label for="christmas">Christmas</label>
</div>
<!-- item 1 -->
        <div class="list-item box"> 

            <!-- img -->
            <div class="img left">
                <img src="img/thumbs/arch-2.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
            </div>

            <!-- data -->
            <div class="block right">
                <p class="date">03/18/2012</p>
                <p class="title">Architecture</p>
                <p class="desc">Architecture is both the process and product of planning, designing and construction. Architectural works, in the material form of buildings, are often perceived as cultural symbols and as works of art. Historical civilizations are often identified with their surviving architectural achievements.</p>
                <p class="like">25 Likes</p>
                <p class="theme">
                    <span class="architecture">Architecture</span>, 
                    <span class="brown">Brown</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: I want to do filtration. I mentioned all my code in question. In my code all the filtration are working on static data. Now I want to perform this filtration on dynamic data.

Comment: I have done with filtration, on static data which I mentioned in the code. Now I want to perform filtration on dynamic data.

Comment: The try that first...and then come back. The way this site works is that you present a given attempt and show the issues you are having with it. The question of "please provide code for me" is not a good question for this site. this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask